Can Razor Pages in referenced DLL be embedded as a resource
I have a solution with 2 projects.  The important parts are structured like this...
 * ProjectA (the main app)
    * Pages
       * _SomePartial.cshtml
       * Page1.cshtml
 * ProjectB (referenced by ProjecA)
    * wwwroot
       * css
         * styles.css
       * js
         * some.js
    * Pages
       * _Layout.cshtml
       * AnotherPage.cshtml

When I publish this, the published folder has a Pages folder containing the pages from ProjectB.  The pages from ProjectA are apparently embed as desired even though I never changed the Build Action from the Default of "Content".
This all works, but I don't want the Pages in the Pages folder where somebody could go edit them.
I tried the obvious thing of setting their Build Action to "Embeded Resource" but then the application can't find them.
I remembered I had to jump through some hoops to get at embed wwwroot files like this:
    var type = typeof(SomeTypeIKnowIsInAssemblyB);
    var assembly = type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var commonFileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly, "MyNamespace.wwwroot");
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { FileProvider = commonFileProvider });

So I added that substituting "Pages" instead of "wwwroot".  No luck.
I did find This StackOverflow Article which seemed promising but made use of system.web.hosting which is old .NET 4.x technology. It looks like it's just the 4.x equivalent of UseStaticFiles and EmbededFileProvider.
So is there any way to embed those Pages from the referenced project?  It seems like there should be.
